# Why was this question about jury nullification deleted by a moderator?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderation, deleted-questions

Moderator [feetwet](https://law.stackexchange.com/users/10/feetwet) has deleted [Are jurors ever told about jury nullification in the US? If not, why not?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/41966/are-jurors-ever-told-about-jury-nullification-in-the-us-if-not-why-not).  This is puzzling.  Why was it deleted?

Comment: I was coming here to ask the same question. My inclination is to repost a slightly modified question along with the latest version of my answer.

Comment: @DavidSiegel indeed, your wasted effort was part of the reason I decided to ask rather than just wonder silently.  But I am also curious, because I cannot think of a reason for the deletion. Nothing in the [relevant help page](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions) seems to apply.

Answer (score 2):

*Oops:* That was flagged for review, and for some reason I thought it was an answer.  I just undeleted it.  Thanks for calling it to my attention!

As a question it doesn't merit deletion, although it's pretty close to [How can a jury know about jury nullification?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/176/10) which was closed as "too broad" (though I didn't vote on that closure), and as initially written the question might also be closed as primarily opinion-based.